# Reshaping a 3D array to a 2D array to produce a DataFrame: keep track of indices to produce column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy-ndarray

The following code generates a `pandas.DataFrame` from a 3D array over the first axis. I manually create the columns names (defining `cols`): is there a more built-in way to do this (to avoid potential errors e.g. regarding C-order)?

--> I am looking for a way to guarantee the respect of the order of the indices after the `reshape` operation (here it relies on the correct order of the iterations over `range(nrow)` and `range(ncol)`).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

nt = 6 ; nrow = 4 ; ncol = 3 ; shp = (nt, nrow, ncol)

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.array(np.random.randint(0, 1000, nt*nrow*ncol)).reshape(shp)

# This is the line I think should be improved --> any numpy function or so?
cols = [str(i) + '-' + str(j) for i in range(nrow) for j in range(ncol)]

adf = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(nt, -1), columns = cols)

print(adf)

   0-0  0-1  0-2  1-0  1-1  1-2  2-0  2-1  2-2  3-0  3-1  3-2
0  684  559  629  192  835  763  707  359    9  723  277  754
1  804  599   70  472  600  396  314  705  486  551   87  174
2  600  849  677  537  845   72  777  916  115  976  755  709
3  847  431  448  850   99  984  177  755  797  659  147  910
4  423  288  961  265  697  639  544  543  714  244  151  675
5  510  459  882  183   28  802  128  128  932   53  901  550
```

---

**EDIT**

Illustrating why I don't like my solution - it is just too easy to make a code which technically works but produce a wrong result (inverting `i` and `j` or `nrow` and `ncol`):

```
wrongcols1 = [str(i) + '-' + str(j) for i in range(ncol) for j in range(nrow)]
adf2 = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(nt, -1), columns=wrongcols1)
print(adf2)
   0-0  0-1  0-2  0-3  1-0  1-1  1-2  1-3  2-0  2-1  2-2  2-3
0  684  559  629  192  835  763  707  359    9  723  277  754
1  804  599   70  472  600  396  314  705  486  551   87  174
2  600  849  677  537  845   72  777  916  115  976  755  709
3  847  431  448  850   99  984  177  755  797  659  147  910
4  423  288  961  265  697  639  544  543  714  244  151  675
5  510  459  882  183   28  802  128  128  932   53  901  550

wrongcols2 = [str(j) + '-' + str(i) for i in range(nrow) for j in range(ncol)]
adf3 = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(nt, -1), columns=wrongcols2)
print(adf3)
   0-0  1-0  2-0  0-1  1-1  2-1  0-2  1-2  2-2  0-3  1-3  2-3
0  684  559  629  192  835  763  707  359    9  723  277  754
1  804  599   70  472  600  396  314  705  486  551   87  174
2  600  849  677  537  845   72  777  916  115  976  755  709
3  847  431  448  850   99  984  177  755  797  659  147  910
4  423  288  961  265  697  639  544  543  714  244  151  675
5  510  459  882  183   28  802  128  128  932   53  901  550
```

Comment: what part of your code are you seeking to improve? the column generation?

Comment: Yes @sammywemmy, I identified the line in the code --> here it relies on my own iterations over `range(nrow)` and `range(ncol)` which is suboptimal and subject to errors... --> How I generate column names should be made less "manually"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see if it fits your use case:

Generate columns via a combination of [np.indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html), [np.dstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) and [np.vstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) :

```
columns = np.vstack(np.dstack(np.indices((nrow, ncol))))

array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 0],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2]])
```

Now convert to string via a combination of [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
columns = ["-".join(map(str, entry)) for entry in columns]
['0-0',
 '0-1',
 '0-2',
 '1-0',
 '1-1',
 '1-2',
 '2-0',
 '2-1',
 '2-2',
 '3-0',
 '3-1',
 '3-2']
```

Let's know how it goes.

Comment: Working fine, thanks! I am surprised there is no more direct `numpy` function to achieve this, though... (just waiting a bit before accepting to see if any other suggestion pops out)

Comment: @ztl, good idea to wait a bit longer; good learning process for me as well. I think the power of numpy functions come from its composability.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `pd.MultiIndex` to construct your hierarchy.

First redefine your `cols` to a `list` of `tuples`:

```
cols = [(i, j) for i in range(nrow) for j in range(ncol)]
```

Then construct the multi index with `cols`:

```
multi_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
```

And build the dataframe:

```
adf = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(nt, -1), columns=multi_cols)
```

**Result:**

```
              0           1           2           3
      0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2
0   684 559 629 192 835 763 707 359   9 723 277 754
1   804 599  70 472 600 396 314 705 486 551  87 174
2   600 849 677 537 845  72 777 916 115 976 755 709
3   847 431 448 850  99 984 177 755 797 659 147 910
4   423 288 961 265 697 639 544 543 714 244 151 675
5   510 459 882 183  28 802 128 128 932  53 901 550
```

**Access of elements:**

```
print(adf[1][2][0])
>>> 763
```

Comment: Thanks @rftr but it still relies on the manual definition of `cols`, which itself relies on the appropriate order in which the iterations on `range(nrow)` and `range(ncol)` are done. I am looking for a solution which guarantees the respect of the order in which the indices are modified after the `reshape` operation...

Comment: @ztl: I saw the answer of @sammywemmy but I also want to learn: Could you please try to explain again what the problem with `range` functions is? I think I did not get that.

Comment: I edited my question to make it more explicit, illustrating with wrong results (that can easily happen though with such a way of defining `cols`...)